# How to sort data by month and year in Android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
cursor = mRecordDB.query(POPDatabase.RECORD_TABLE, new String[] 
             { POPDatabase.RECORD_ID, 
               POPDatabase.RECORD_DATE, 
               POPDatabase.RECORD_DETAILS, 
               POPDatabase.RECORD_DEBIT, 
               POPDatabase.RECORD_CREDIT, 
               POPDatabase.RECORD_COMPANY 
              }, null, null,null, null, POPDatabase.RECORD_DATE + " ASC ");
```

This query displays:

```
01-09-2013
02-09-2013
03-08-2013
04-08-2013
05-09-2013
```

But I want to sort by month like this:

```
03-08-2013
04-08-2013
01-09-2013
02-09-2013
05-09-2013
```

Comment: The data in this cursor is already sorted by the `RECORD_DATE` column. What is that not what you want?

Comment: But,Here Data is sort by month Which is enter by user and same as for year. for ex. if user enter 08 month then it display only that month record.

Comment: and month,year are in date column. it like data is sort by substring of RECORD_DATE column.

Comment: Please edit your question to show some example records, how they are sorted now, and how you actually want them to be sorted.

Comment: please reply and resolve that issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("SELECT EndUsers.Name as EndUserName , DistributorMaster.* FROM DistributorMaster,EndUsers where EndUsers.SAPCode=DistributorMaster.CreatedBy order by ID DESC",null);
```

or
Query has two syntax, the syntax you are using, last column represents order by, you just need to specify on what column you want to do orderby +"ASC" (or) orderby +"DESC"

```
Cursor c = scoreDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, rank, null, null, null, null, yourColumn+" DESC");
```

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation to understand more about query method.

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: Here Data is sort by month Which is enter by user and same as for year. for ex. if user enter 08 month then it display only that month record.

Comment: `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SESSION, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, 
        KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_DURATION, KEY_SESSION_TYPE, KEY_ROOM},
        null, null, null, null, KEY_DAY_ID + " ASC, " + KEY_START_TIME  + " ASC");`

Comment: i'm not able to understand plz can u give to ans edit with my query.

Comment: and month,year are in date column. it like data is sort by substring of RECORD_DATE column.

Comment: `SELECT *, strftime("%m" ,datefield) as date_column  FROM datetimetble order by date_column desc`

Comment: can is it write in that form : Cursor c = mRecordDB.rawQuery(SELECT *, strftime("%m" ,datefield) as date_column FROM datetimetble order by date_column desc);

Comment: Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("SELECT *, strftime("%m" ,datefield) as date_column FROM datetimetble order by date_column desc,
    null);